# Uniqueness conjecture

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

Define an H-Triple (a, b, c), where a > b > c > 1, as one where a, b and c = $\frac{ab+1}{a+b}$ are all integers. (There are 'lots' of these!)

Conjecture; if (a, b, c) and (d, e, f) are distinct H-Triples, then abc$\neq$def.

That is, the product of the terms of an H-Triple is unique.

Can anybody help with this? Computers suggest any counterexample will not be small.

The reason the problem arises? Consider the family of elliptic curves $xy\frac{xy+1}{x+y}=k$ and the integer points that lie on them. If (a,b,c) is an H-Triple and k = abc then (a,b) is an integer point on this elliptic curve. The uniqueness conjecture would narrow down the possibility that there might be any others.

Comment: I don't think the conjecture is phrased perfectly.  For example, for the distinct triples

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250172/when-is-fa-b-fraca2b21ab-a-perfect-square-rational-number/250300#250300

Comment: @individ But this is $f(a,b)=\frac{a^2+b^2}{1+ab}$, and not  $\frac{ab+1}{a+b}$?

Comment: By distinct triples I mean that (a, b, c) is not equal to (d, e, f).

Comment: @individ the original version of this problem is I think famously the only question that Terry Tao did not solve at the IMO where he won a gold medal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea to search for a counterexample. We have the following universal $H$-triples, namely
$$
(a, b ,c)=(2k+1,2k-1,k),\; (r^2+r-1,r+1,r)
$$
for all $k,r\ge 1$.
Equality of their products means
$$
4k^3-k=r^4+2r^3-r
$$
This Diophantine equation has the "trivial" solution $(k,r)=(2,2)$. In this case the triples coincide and are $(a, b,c)=(5,3,2)$ with product $abc=30$. With a computer one could try to find a non-trivial solution in positive integers, if it exists. This would yield two different $H$-triples with equal product. Of course one may use also different universal triples, like $(a,b,c)=(2l^2+4l+1,2l+3,2l+1)$ and others.

Comment: I did try this approach, but I didn't use the particular parametrised H-triples that you suggest, which seem to me to have a better chance of working than mine. Let me try this on the computer...

Comment: Tried this using VBA/Excel running k and r up to 5000 - no counterexample. An alternative approach; count the H-triples with all elements less than 1,000 say, then count their products.  Do the numbers match?

Comment: I generated the 418902 triples with $a<100000$, and none were found to have the same $abc$.